# GraphQL query returns error "Cannot return null for non-nullable field"

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

I have a basic GraphQL query setup as follows:

**Query.js:**

```
const Query = {
    dogs(parent, args, ctx, info) {
        return [{ name: 'Snickers' }, { name: 'Sunny' }];
    },
};

module.exports = Query;
```

---

**schema.graphql:**

```
type Dog {
    name: String!
}
type Query {
    dogs: [Dog]!
}
```

---

I created a function `createServer()` for starting the server as follows:

```
const { GraphQLServer } = require('graphql-yoga');
const Mutation = require('./resolvers/Mutation');
const Query = require('./resolvers/Query');
const db = require('./db');

function createServer() {
    return new GraphQLServer({
        typeDefs: 'src/schema.graphql',
        resolvers: {
            Mutation,
            Query,
        },
        resolverValidationOptions: {
            requireResolversForResolveType: false,
        },
        context: req => ({ ...req, db }),
    });
}

module.exports = createServer;
```

I then tried querying `dogs` as follows:

```
query {
  dogs {
    name
  }
}
```

But instead of getting the names from the array of dogs, I got the following error instead:

```
{
  "data": null,
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Query.dogs.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "dogs"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What seems to be causing this error?

Comment: Sounds like you're not importing Query.js correctly or your resolvers are not set up correctly. Please show the rest of the relevant code, including how you're constructing the resolvers object and how you're providing the type defs and resolvers to the GraphQLServer constructor.

Comment: @DanielRearden Ok hold on.

Comment: @DanielRearden My `prisma.graphql` has more than 300 lines of code. Should I copy a certain part of it or do you want me to copy the whole thing?

Comment: Not sure if any other type defs are relevant. I expect you have code that looks something like this: https://github.com/prisma/prisma-examples/blob/master/typescript/graphql/src/index.ts and maybe a separate file like this https://github.com/prisma/prisma-examples/blob/master/typescript/graphql/src/resolvers/index.ts

Comment: @DanielRearden Question updated!!

Comment: Odd, I can run a `graphql-yoga` server with the above typeDefs and resolvers with no problems. Unless `./resolvers/Query` is not the right path for `Query`, I'm not sure what else could be wrong :/

Comment: If it were an incorrect path node wouldn't be able to resolve it and would throw an error: `"Error: Cannot find module ..."` and the server would be down. It looks like it does resolve, but to an empty object, so the `dogs` resolver is not there. Are you sure `Query.js` exports are correct?

Comment: @IonutAchim Is there any way I can check if the `Query.js` exports are correct? I added a `console.log("Query: " + Query)` inside the `createServer()` function and it returned `Query: [Object Object]`.

Comment: @AndrewL, best way is to check the module exports. The console log can be misleading. If you were to not export anything, it would resolve to an empty object. So just inspect the file and see what your exports are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code works as you can see in codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/olzj9vvpk5

But when I convert Query to something like `{}` it returns the same error so please check your paths and console.log Query to validate the path. Your export looks correct but you might have forgotten to save the file as I can see from the course starter files Query is an `{}`. Please double check.

Also if this code is in a public git repo please share the link.

Comment: The problem was with a typo in one of my files apparently. I marked your answer as correct regardless because your codepen helped me in finding the typo. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been answered, but for me the only thing that fixed this issue was to also pass the info argument.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I create a new Query.js file at the src folder but I import Query with Query = require('./resolvers/Query') and coding there. So, try to check the path, I think the problem is there.

Answer (score 0):

This problem comes from AWS requiring certain standard values in the dynamoDB table, such as createdAt and updatedAd, just add these fields manually with a timestamp in dynamo db for further testing. A mutation always needs to be requested via id, this somehow was not clear to me when my schema was created by amplify codegen...